# SpringBootTest random port access in companion object

Tags: java, spring-boot, kotlin, spring-boot-test, testcontainers

Im struggling with getting the "spring" generated random port for tests where it would be needed in a companion object for mapping my config to the proper testcontainer port

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = [Application::class], webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
class Test {
 companion object {
        @JvmStatic
        @LocalServerPort
        protected var testPort = 0

        @JvmStatic
        @DynamicPropertySource
        fun registerProps(registry: DynamicPropertyRegistry) {
            println("opening port $testPort ")
            TestContainers.exposeHostPorts(testPort)
            OpsContainer.start()
            registry.add("service.ops.port", testPort)
        }
    }

  @Test
  fun basicTest() {
    .
    .
    .
  }
}
```

If I try and put LocalServerPort inside the companion object it wont initialize "correctly" but will have the default value of 0. If I move it out of the companion it "works" but then I cant bind my config to the spring port as that needs to happen in a companion.

I have tried a few different combinations but seem to be in a position where a needs b, and at the same time, b depends on a.

Comment: IDK what do you want in here, you want to test what? If only you need to specific port: you can use profile test, or 
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT) https://rieckpil.de/guide-to-springboottest-for-spring-boot-integration-tests/. like you did, but what's the point?

Comment: I want to expose the port spring uses for my testcontainer

Comment: I will send you this https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-running-port

Comment: Is this a Kotlin specific issue? Your pattern should generally work using the `@DynamicPropertySource`. If you use `container.withAccessToHost(true)`, you can also expose the host after the container started, see https://www.testcontainers.org/features/networking/#exposing-host-ports-to-the-container.

Comment: container.withAccessToHost(true) workaround solves the issue for me, then I can just expose the port in a beforeall. Thanks